# Thread - is it a static duration object?

Tags: c++, multithreading

As the title says: is a `std::thread` a static duration object? Or does it use some even if I don't access static variables explicitly?

Edit:

n2440 says (Abandoning a Process):

> The primary problem with destruction of static-duration objects is access to static-duration objects after their destructors have executed, thus resulting in undefined behavior. To prevent this problem, N2382 Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency requires that all user threads finish before destruction begins (via a call to exit or return from main).

so does this hold even if the thread doesn't explicitly access any variable marked `static`?

Comment: what's 'static duration object'?

Comment: Your question is vague, please edit to make it more explicit. "*Or does it use some*" ?

Comment: Clarifying and adding more details. I can't be more clear than this

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` is a class, it does not any storage duration.

Objects (or instances) of `std::thread` can have any storage duration (static (a global), automatic (on the stack), dynamic (in the heap)).

n2440 (Abandoning a Process) is concerned with accessing global objects after they have been destroyed. Which may happen when `main` returns but there are still extra threads running and accessing global objects (e.g. `std::cout`) which are now being destroyed by the main thread.

Comment: so it doesn't apply if I create a `std::thread` on `main()` that does nothing aside from spinning in an endless loop since it won't have any static storage duration, right?

Comment: @Dean It depends how you create `std::thread` (stack or heap) and whether it is detached. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0206r0.html